# Do google mobile vision text only works on certain smarthphones?

Tags: android

I'm triying to apply the example from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#8
but i can't make it work on my Moto E5 play but it works on a huawei MYA-L13

Also im getting this error constantly on the logcat:

```
"Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found."
```

It's the first time i ask on this site. I hope that I could explain myself well.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The "Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found" is benign, it has nothing to do with if your detector is operational or not. That's why it's a warning instead of error.

Can you check if your device is at low storage? That's the most common reason why detector doesn't work. and if your device has enough storage space then try to Establishing an internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for answering! No, it actually has 10 gb of free space and my google play services version is 15.0.90

Comment: I have a hint! maybe it not works on my moto E5 play because it has installed micro g services